# Have an error while creating new product in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dictionary, controller, categories

undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  tap

Product controller

```
 <%= f.input  :title , label: "Name of the product: " %>
  <%= f.input  :description, label: "Description of the product: " %>
  <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :promt => "Category")%>
  <%= f.input  :price, as: :integer , label: "Price of the product: " %>
  <%= f.input  :discount, label: "Discount for the product" %>
  <%= f.input  :image, as: :file,label: "Please upload image of the product" %>
```

Here that error that appears in console

```
Cannot render console from 89.218.94.140! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PSg52JmMvZq3dLjje4cEYuYe4ySr3v0DMx5pLv723KKYnQ0awd+ypWii+foe4c6HV6ddq1xEuyFMUwAgBNS0sA==", "product"=>{"title"=>"For her", "description"=>"Gentle and beauty", "price"=>"8000", "discount"=>"3300", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd3f0cd2140 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170628-4090-3uc3bp.jpg>, @original_filename="705c9f06e0f2a2b960d54813b871e7eb.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[image]\"; filename=\"705c9f06e0f2a2b960d54813b871e7eb.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "available"=>"1"}, "category_id"=>"1", "commit"=>"Create Product"}
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/65a151e5e2c95cb454ff8af39951145320170628-4090-rlpn75.jpg'
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/65a151e5e2c95cb454ff8af39951145320170628-4090-9s8vu4.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; identify -format %m '/tmp/65a151e5e2c95cb454ff8af39951145320170628-4090-9s8vu4.jpg[0]'
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; convert '/tmp/65a151e5e2c95cb454ff8af39951145320170628-4090-9s8vu4.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "600x600>" '/tmp/a5967e19d796bb8d7db2a350531f598020170628-4090-7kuj4w'
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/65a151e5e2c95cb454ff8af39951145320170628-4090-9s8vu4.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; identify -format %m '/tmp/65a151e5e2c95cb454ff8af39951145320170628-4090-9s8vu4.jpg[0]'
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; convert '/tmp/65a151e5e2c95cb454ff8af39951145320170628-4090-9s8vu4.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "300x300>" '/tmp/a5967e19d796bb8d7db2a350531f598020170628-4090-zf5vc5'
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/65a151e5e2c95cb454ff8af39951145320170628-4090-9s8vu4.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; identify -format %m '/tmp/65a151e5e2c95cb454ff8af39951145320170628-4090-9s8vu4.jpg[0]'
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; convert '/tmp/65a151e5e2c95cb454ff8af39951145320170628-4090-9s8vu4.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "150x" -crop "150x0+0+102" +repage '/tmp/a5967e19d796bb8d7db2a350531f598020170628-4090-1c398r8'
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; file -b --mime '/tmp/65a151e5e2c95cb454ff8af39951145320170628-4090-fyglg3.jpg'
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering products/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered products/_form.html.erb (5.9ms)
  Rendered products/new.html.erb within layouts/application (7.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 346ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Comment: Can u share the console log as well as the Products controller code

Comment: @Aashish
Here's code of creating product in Product Controller:
 def new
  '@'product = Product.new
  '@'categories = Category.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}
 end

 def create
  '@'product = Product.new(product_params)
   '@'product.category_id = params[:category_id]
  if '@'product.save
   redirect_to root_path
  else
   render 'new'
  end
 end

and console gives the same error:
Cannot render console from 89.218.94.140! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255

Comment: Please add the log in the question itself. So anyone reading your question need not to read the comment section as well to find this log.

Answer (score 1):

> undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

`@categories` is undefined. Make sure you have defined `@categories` in the relevant `controller#action`

Also, you are writing it wrong. [*options_for_select*](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) expects container(either a hash/array/enumerable)

> Accepts a container (hash, array, enumerable, your type) and returns a
>   string of option tags. Given a container where the elements respond to
>   first and last (such as a two-element array), the “lasts” serve as
>   option values and the “firsts” as option text. Hashes are turned into
>   this form automatically, so the keys become “firsts” and values become
>   lasts. If selected is specified, the matching “last” or element will
>   get the selected option-tag.

You need to change it to something like

```
<%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id] }), :prompt => "Category")%>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using the `simple_form`, So for display `select` tag you have below options

**Option#1**

```
f.input :category_id, collection: @categories, prompt: 'Category'
```

Make sure `@categories` contains the array elements

**Option#2**

Use `simple_form` [Associations](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations) as below (Visit link for more details)

```
  f.association :category, prompt: 'Category'
```

Hope this will help you to resolve your problem

Comment: Tried both of options, it didn't give me the error, but it redirected me to the /products page, but instead of page of product there is the view of the same form :/ Anyway, thanks for  help, think that there are another problems deeper in code

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

You are probably getting this error in your view, on line:

```
<%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :promt => "Category")%>
```

This means that `@categories` variable is `undefined` in your controller action serving up this view which is most probably `ProductsController#new`. Make sure that you are assigning value to `@categories` variable in that action, for e.g.

```
@categories = Category.all
```

UPDATE:

As mentioned in your comment, if you have assigned the variable `@categories` in controller like

```
def new 
  @product = Product.new 
  @categories = Category.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]} 
end
```

then make sure the table `Category` has values. It seems like `Category.all` is returning `nil` which is causing this error. You could test it easily by starting `rails console` on your terminal and running `Category.all` command on it.

Comment: Here I create new product and defiine categories                                    def new
  "@"product = Product.new
  "@"categories = Category.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}
 end

Comment: @AlinaDyussupova Where? Can you update your question with `ProductsController` code and also share the complete error stack trace.

Comment: @AlinaDyussupova I have added an UPDATE section to my answer as per your comment.

Comment: Category Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Category id: 1, name: "Bouquets", created_at: "2017-06-27 15:30:41", updated_at: "2017-06-27 15:30:41">, #<Category id: 2, name: "Mono", created_at: "2017-06-27 15:31:12", updated_at: "2017-06-27 15:31:12">]> 
2.3.0 :002 > 


I have categories and still don't understans why it doesn't work. The thing is that this code successfully runs in another computer, but after I've loaded it on mine it gives me that error

Comment: @AlinaDyussupova Did you run migrations on your computer? Also, did you get the above results for `Category.all` on _your_ computer which is giving error?

Comment: Yes, run migrations, and yes, did it all on my computer. I use cloud9 services and even tried to do all this steps in another project but still gives the same error results

Comment: @AlinaDyussupova Could you edit and update your question with entire error stack trace that could help in pin pointing where exactly is the error being encountered.